# Mysql Get First null row among non nulls

Tags: mysql

I have this table structure:

```
quiz_id   id    end_utc
 40       40    2018-09-15 23:59:59
 41       41    2018-09-15 23:59:59
 42       42    2018-09-15 23:59:59
NULL      43    2018-09-15 23:59:59
NULL      45    2018-09-15 23:59:59
```

I want to get the first null row's id, in this case, 43, the query I currently have is this:

```
select DISTINCT answers.quiz_id as quiz_id, 
         id, 
        end_utc FROM quiz 
LEFT JOIN answers ON quiz.id = answers.quiz_id AND answers.is_active = 
1 AND answers.player_id = 1 WHERE contest_id = 2
```

If I try, `AND quiz_id IS NULL`, then it returns both 43 and 45, however, the first 3 rows are missing.

Any help is appreciated. Also, got something `Top 1 *` for SQL server, but doesn't work in MySQL.

Thanks!

PS:

Can we have expected output like this :

```
 quiz_id      id    end_utc
 40       40    2018-09-15 23:59:59
 41       41    2018-09-15 23:59:59
 42       42    2018-09-15 23:59:59
NULL      43    2018-09-15 23:59:59
```

Comment: `Top 1` is SQL Server Syntax in mysql it is `limit 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Union](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) to get results for two cases separately.

Try the following:

```
(
select DISTINCT answers.quiz_id as quiz_id, 
                id, 
                end_utc 
FROM quiz 
INNER JOIN answers ON quiz.id = answers.quiz_id 
                     AND answers.is_active = 1 
                     AND answers.player_id = 1 
WHERE contest_id = 2 
ORDER BY answers.id ASC 
)

UNION ALL 

(
select DISTINCT answers.quiz_id as quiz_id, 
                id, 
                end_utc 
FROM quiz 
LEFT JOIN answers ON quiz.id = answers.quiz_id 
                     AND answers.is_active = 1 
                     AND answers.player_id = 1 
WHERE contest_id = 2 
  AND answers.quiz_id IS NULL 
ORDER BY answers.id ASC LIMIT 1
)

ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: I tried the given query, however, it doesn't return the correct id.

Comment: Please run this first: 

select DISTINCT answers.quiz_id as quiz_id, 
                id, 
                end_utc 
FROM quiz 
LEFT JOIN answers ON quiz.id = answers.quiz_id 
                     AND answers.is_active = 1 
                     AND answers.player_id = 1 
WHERE contest_id = 2 
  AND answers.quiz_id IS NULL 

And share the result, what you get. I believe your original attempt may be in wrong direction

Comment: This returns 

 quiz_id id end_utc
NULL 43 2018-09-15 23:59:59
NULL 45 2018-09-15 23:59:59

All the null values. BTW, please check the updated question.

Comment: @KinshukLahiri I have edited the answer. please check the update

Comment: This will count as 1 query or 2 since, we are using Select twice?

Comment: @KinshukLahiri This is overall one single query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180416/discussion-between-madhur-bhaiya-and-kinshuk-lahiri).